# '... is followed by...'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> There is some footage of the Second World War. This is followed by some more printed words.

Is it correct to use 'is followed by' in this context? The sentences are about a video.

Comment: Yes: it's perfect English.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you might have asked this question. "There is" might be seen as a little vague: "There exists somewhere". However, assuming the context is a web page, "there is" as a [demonstrative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative) means the same as "here is". "This" refers back to the footage introduced in the first sentence.

> There/Here is some footage of the Second World War. This [footage] is followed by some more printed words.

If this is something you are writing yourself, an improvement is:

> **Here** is some footage of the Second World War. This is followed by some **explanatory text**.